# Python PIL concatenate images

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a project where I need to concatenate a lot of images (80282). Each image is 256 x 256 pixels, and some of the files are empty (no image), so I need to create a blank image to replace the file. I have the data in this format: data-D0H0-X52773-Y14041

X and Y correspond to the coordinates that I need to concatenate in order. The order is from the top left X52773-Y14314 to the bottom right X52964-Y14041. It is 294 iterations on X and 274 on Y. Here is the code I have written which is not working correctly, I could use any help if you have an idea, currently, my images are not well aligned on Y. For example, the image X10-Y10 is not under the image X10-Y11 as it should. I think I have some problem using correctly the try: and except:
Thanks for you help !

```
from PIL import Image

width = 75264
height = 70144
new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (75264, 70144))

x_offset = 0
y_offset = 0

coordinate = {}
coordinate['x']=52672 
coordinate['y']=14314

#top image line should be from:    X52,672-Y14,314 to X52,965-Y14,314
#bottom image line should be from: X52,672-Y14,041 to X52,965-Y14,041

for irow in range(0, 274): 
    for icol in range(0, 294): 
        try:
            if (x_offset == width):
                coordinate['y'] = coordinate['y'] - 1
                coordinate['x'] = 52672
            img = Image.open("data-D0H0-X"+str(coordinate['x'])+"-Y"+str(coordinate['y'])+".png")

        except:
            coordinate['x'] = coordinate['x'] + 1
            blank = Image.new('RGBA', (256,256))
            new_im.paste(blank, (x_offset, y_offset))
            x_offset += 256
            if (x_offset == width):
                x_offset = 0
                y_offset += 256
            break

        new_im.paste(img, (x_offset, y_offset))
        x_offset += 256
        if (x_offset == width):
            x_offset = 0
            y_offset += 256
        coordinate['x'] = coordinate['x'] + 1


new_im.show()
new_im.save('full_image.png')
```

EDIT:
Here is the new code I've modified according to your answer. However, I'm still getting an error: 
    struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295

Not sure if my coordinate calcul is right now.

CODE:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import imghdr

width = 75264
height = 70144

new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))

for filename in glob.glob('data-D0H0-X*.png'):
    tmp_arr = filename.split('-')
    x_coord = int(tmp_arr[2][1:6])
    y_coord = int(tmp_arr[3][1:6])

    info = imghdr.what(filename)
    if (info == "png"):
        new_img = Image.open(filename)
    else:
        new_img = Image.new('RGBA', (256,256))


    x_coord = (x_coord-52672)*256
    y_coord = (14314-y_coord)*256
    print x_coord, y_coord
    new_im.paste(new_img, (x_coord, y_coord))

new_im.show()
new_im.save('full_image.png')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your coordinate arithmetic seems a bit off. Since your images are 256x256 you should never have to inc/dec x and y by 1 as you do in your code.
The code below hasn't been tested but should provide a general outline.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob

width = 75264
height = 70144
new_im = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))

for filename in glob.glob('data-D0H0-X*.png'):
    tmp_arr = filename.split('-')
    x_coord = int(tmp_arr[2][1:])
    y_coord = int(tmp_arr[3][1:])
    small_img = Image.open(filename)
    new_im.paste(small_img, (x_coord, y_coord))

new_im.show()
new_im.save('full_image.png')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it helped me ! I just have one more question, how can I have a white image for the times when I have nothing in the file ? Currently, with the code, it says: IOError: cannot identify image file 'data-D0H0-X52673-Y14072.png' when it comes to files with no data.

Comment: Well, you could get rid of empty files beforehand or add a check to disregard files with zero size in the loop: import os; 
for filename in glob.glob('data-D0H0-X*.png'): if os.stat(filename).st_size != 0:..

Comment: Hi, I found a way to check for the file using "imghdr.what()". I've edited my 1st post with the idea of your help. I'm still getting an error, do you have an idea how could I solve it ?

Comment: Why are you multiplying everything by 256 when you already have the correct coordinates in the file name?

Comment: The coordinate in the filename are from 52672 to 52965 on X and from 14314 to 14041 on Y. Not from 0 to the width/length of the new image, so how can it paste it at the correct place with the original coordinates ? I thought we have to indicate the place where to paste. The pixels' image is from 0 to the width/length of the created image (Image.new('RGBA', (width, height))) Am I getting something wrong ?

Comment: Also my Y max is on the top and decrease while with .paste(), Y increase from the top to the bottom if I m correct